# Showing that $\{0,1\}^{n}$ is a complete lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

Consider the set $\{0,1\}^{n}$ of $n\times 1$ vectors composed of zeros or ones.

E.g. for $n=2$ $\{0,1\}^{n}\equiv \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$.

Assume coordinate-wise comparison between vectors: $\forall Y, Y'$
$$
Y\geq Y' \Leftrightarrow Y_i\geq Y'_i \text{ } \forall i=1,...,n
$$

Could you help me to show that $\{0,1\}^{n}$ is a complete lattice?

Comment: Finite lattices do tend to be complete.

Comment: Given any non-empty set $X$, there is an order-isomorphism between $\{0,1\}^X$ and the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $f \in \{0,1\}^X$ corresponds to $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ if and only if the following is true:$$ \forall x \in A \ : \ [f(x) = 1 \ \Leftrightarrow \ x \in A]. $$ And we know that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a complete lattice. Or more directly, for each non-empty subset $S$ of $\{0,1\}^X$, you can check that $$ \vee S := x \mapsto \sup_{f \in S} f(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \wedge S := x \mapsto \inf_{f\in S} f(x) $$ are the supremum of $S$ (resp. infimum of $S$).